# RoR Render errors partial if edit fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

the problem I have is probably easy to solve, although I did a lot of search and cant find a solution.

I have in my _errors.html.erb

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">
   <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h2 class="panel-title">
        <%= pluralize(obj.errors.count, "error") %>
        prohibided this form from being saved:
      </h2>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Then I have in my edit.html.erb that has a form and:

```
<%= render 'layouts/errors', obj: @my_obj_here %>
```

Then in the controller update/create (lets use the update as example):

```
def update
    if @my_obj_here.update(params[:my_obj_here].permit(:body))
        redirect_to my_path_here_path(@my_obj_here), notice: "Something."
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
 end
```

The issue happens when I try to update and the submit info is invalid, which will fall into the "render 'edit'"

The errors show correctly (in this case max length 100) but my url changes from:
**my_obj_here/1/edit** to **my_obj_here/1**

which should not happen.

So next I tried replacing the "render 'edit'" with `"redirect_to :back"` but this just ignores the 
`<%= render 'layouts/errors', obj: @my_obj_here %>` in the edit.html.erb.

Can someone help me out figuring out how to render the same **my_obj_here/1/edit**? 
I believe I need to use the "render" my method because the redirect will just skip the errors partial.

Also, in my update method you probably noticed this "if true":
`redirect_to my_path_here_path(@my_obj_here), notice: "Something."`
I could the the same and just change my code to:
`redirect_to :back, :notice => "something."`
This would work, but does not show the errors as I want them to shown when my the errors partial is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The errors show correctly (in this case max length 100) but my url
>   changes from: my_obj_here/1/edit to my_obj_here/1 which should not
>   happen.

This is is a very common misconception. Rails uses RESTful conventions where the HTTP methods used are extremely important.

When you click an edit link it you're performing a GET request to `my_obj_here/1/edit`. This is an idempotent action - the result is always the same and it does not alter any resource. In fact the `new` and `edit` actions in Rails don't do anything but display forms.

When you submit the form your sending a PATCH request to `my_obj_here/1`. This is a non-idempotent request as it alters the resource. When the validation fails and you render you're actually displaying the result of an attempt to update a resource. This is fundamentally different than the GET request to `my_obj_here/1/edit` - it's not cacheable and cannot be revisited.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: that looks correct, thanks for your reply. I've checked other apps and all do the same thing, after the error the url changes and loses the /edit.
So now there's another question, once here: my_obj_here/1 what do I need to have in the show page to make sure I stay in that same edit after a refresh?
Example:
**1 -** we are here: my_obj_here/1/edit
**2 -** we force an error and we go to my_obj_here/1 with the error messages showing
**3 -** Refresh page
This is now the "show" instead of the "edit".

Comment: You don't. Refreshing the page performs a `GET my_obj_here/1` request which is not the same at all. Thats an idempotent request that should provide the same result no matter of the state. This is actually less of an issue than you think. I would encourage you to keep an open mind and a focus on why REST is built the way it is rather than on how you think it should work.

Comment: If you really want the user not to lose state than use javascript to set a `window.onunload` handler. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload